# why does gcc(default version on openSUSE 11.3) give an error on the statement int *p=malloc(sizeof(int));?

Tags: gcc, casting, malloc

malloc returns a void pointer.so why is it not working for me without typecasting the return value?
The error pretty clear said that gcc is not allowing conversion from void* to int*.

Comment: What's the error? post it.

Comment: have you included the "StdLib.h" header file?

Comment: @Abhineet, that's not a valid header, you mean `stdlib.h` (all lowercase)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yeah ofcourse, working on Windows have made me so "CamelCased". :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you don't have to cast. In fact it's a bad idea to cast there since it can cause certain subtle errors.

However, casting *is* required in C++ so that would be my first guess, that you're somehow invoking the C++ compiler. Perhaps your source files are `*.cpp` or `*.C` both of which may be auto-magigically treated as C++ rather than C.

See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html) for more detail:

> C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes ‘.C’, ‘.cc’, ‘.cpp’, ‘.CPP’, ‘.c++’, ‘.cp’, or ‘.cxx’; C++ header files often use ‘.hh’, ‘.hpp’, ‘.H’, or (for shared template code) ‘.tcc’; and preprocessed C++ files use the suffix ‘.ii’. GCC recognizes files with these names and compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name gcc).

The fact that it *knows* you're trying to convert `void*` to `int*` means that you have a valid `malloc` prototype in place so I can't see it being anything other than the imposition of C++ rules.

Comment: Thank you! I cross-checked.Turns out my IDE was generating a .cpp extension as default.Though wasn't aware that C++ doesn't allow it without typecasting.I think it defies the purpose of declaring a pointer as void but there would be a reason I suppose.

Comment: I used the IDE in windows to write the code and compiled with GCC.Then compiled the same source file with GCC in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Without code I can't help you properly, but you can try this:

```
p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Give more info about what you want to do and what you are allocating.

Comment: yes this works but you shouldn't be needing to typecast a void pointer.